# How to minimize C++ function using boost?

Tags: c++, function, boost, std, minimize

so I have a function like

```
int f(int i, int j, int c, double d) {
    /*...any operations with i, j, c, d affect on some return int we have*/
}
```

Is there any thing in boost or STD that would take my function and find the input arguments that minimize my function output?

Comment: Boost cannot magically know what your function does with the arguments at run-time.

Comment: This isn't a question that anyone can answer in its current form. Please provide more details about what your function is supposed to do (ideally including the function's code), and explain what you mean by "[minimizing] my function output."

Comment: There are techniques for finding the arguments that minimize or maximize the output of a black-box function, provided it is a function in the mathematical sense.  I think that's what Kabumbus wants.

Comment: @Zack: Thanks for the helpful interpretation. I'd withdraw my vote to close, but there doesn't seem to be a way that I can do that. I made some slight edits to the question to slant it towards your interpretation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand you to be looking for code to perform [mathematical optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_%28mathematics%29).

Boost does not have anything to do this as far as I know, and neither does the standard library; however, [NLopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're trying to do a "simple" mathematical multi-dimensional minimization.

[GSL has some functions to help you with this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/multimin.html). I wouldn't look any further `;)`

Comment: Please read the information given to you: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multimin-Examples.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use Brent's algorithm to minimise simple functions.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/roots/brent_minima.html

Comment: The documentation is missing in newer versions of Boost but you can still use the code. Just follow the example found in your Boost download: boost_1_62_0\libs\math\example\brent_minimise_example.cpp